# node_modules don't exist in Jenkins build image

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am running Jenkins from a Dockerfile, and have successfully integrated with Bitbucket cloud using the local docker.sock. I have setup a new pipeline using Blue Ocean which downloads the repo and builds a simple nodejs app from the Dockerfile.

My files look like this :

Node app

```
  

    FROM node:8.6.0-slim
    WORKDIR app
    # Install dependencies
    COPY package.json .
    RUN npm install
    RUN ls
    # Import source files
    COPY . .
```

Jenkinsfile

```
    pipeline {
        agent { dockerfile true }
        stages {
            stage('Test') {
                steps {
                    sh 'ls -l'
                    sh 'npm test'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However when I run the `npm test` step, it is complaining that it can't find the `node_modules`. The step works fine if I run `npm install` from the Jenkinsfile like `sh 'npm install'`.

Maybe I am missing something but it looks like jenkins is not running the steps in the build image, which means I have to replicate the `npm install` and potentially other commands both in the app `Dockerfile` and the `Jenkinsfile`.

Is there a way to run the tests in the image originally built or do I have to replicate the build steps from the `Dockerfile` to the `Jenkinsfile`?

Comment: Try `sh 'pwd'` - you'll see that it copied your git repo into a different directory

Comment: Ever figure this out? My image doesn't seem to find the node_modules install I did.

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins mounts the project in its own directory. If you use the `dockerfile` arg it won't necessarily install your dependencies in the right place.

If you look in the console for your build you should see a line like this:

```
docker run -t -d -u 500:500 -w /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ev-team_***_master-D5DTMAWQCFAZ7O7BLEJB3CZGNIHTH72HCI7AEOKAAA7A4XQN3COQ -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ev-***_master-D5DTMAWQCFAZ7O7BLEJB3CZGNIHTH72HCI7AEOKAAA7A4XQN3COQ:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ev-team_**_master-D5DTMAWQCFAZ7O7BLEJB3CZGNIHTH72HCI7AEOKAAA7A4XQN3COQ:rw,z -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ev-team_**_master-D5DTMAWQCFAZ7O7BLEJB3CZGNIHTH72HCI7AEOKAAA7A4XQN3COQ@tmp:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ev-team_**_master-D5DTMAWQCFAZ7O7BLEJB3CZGNIHTH72HCI7AEOKAAA7A4XQN3COQ@tmp:rw,z -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** 53c72bed1642cf1703ce0385a7b622121709b9af cat
```

Note the the `-w` and `-v` flags. Jenkins mounts into those directories which is different than the WRKDIR that you specify in your Dockerfile above.

I haven't yet found a great solution to this except installing dependencies globally but that also isn't great. If others have fixed this in other ways I'd love to know.

Comment: I was able to access my node_modules with a symlink
`ln -s <path-to-workdir>/node_modules node_modules`

Answer (score 1):

During docker build Jenkins executes `npm install` instruction from Dockerfile.

But, as [dkez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3735630/dkez) correctly said, Jenkins mounts his workspace to image, so `npm test` executed in `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/job_name` and leads to missing `mode_module` folder error.

You may specify folder where `npm` command will be executed, so just point it to your `workdir`:

```
    pipeline {
        agent { dockerfile true }
        stages {
            stage('Test') {
                steps {
                    sh 'ls -l'
                    sh 'npm test --prefix app'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```